# Подключение картинок на сайте в зависимости от времени года (месяца)

Tags: javascript, php, изображения

Подскажите, как подключать разные картинки в зимнее и летнее время автоматически. Есть ли такой скрипт, или может это будет php код? И есть ли у кого-то опыт работы с такой задачей, то поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Подсказываю: если номер месяца такой-то - подключаете такую-то картинку.

Comment: В общем-то то же самое что я вам подсказал - написали в ответе, но окей, вам лучше знать.

Comment: Я изначально понимал алгоритм или задумку того, как это сделать. Задача ведь по сути проста, но если бы я знал как её реализовать, то я бы сюда не обращался за помощью. И Вы мне пишете "Если хочешь передвинуть объект А, подойди, возьми его у руки, передвинь - готово".

Comment: @Стас именно поэтому вопрос надо формулировать точнее.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#winter, #spring, #summer, #autumn").hide();

var date = new Date().getMonth();

if(date == 11 || date == 0 || date == 1) $("#winter").show(); // зима
if(date == 2 || date == 3 || date == 4) $("#spring").show(); // весна
if(date == 5 || date == 6 || date == 7) $("#summer").show(); // лето
if(date == 8 || date == 9 || date == 10) $("#autumn").show(); // осень
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="winter" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Kuznetsk_Alatau_3.jpg/220px-Kuznetsk_Alatau_3.jpg">
<img id="spring" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Teva_17_3_%2869%29.JPG/220px-Teva_17_3_%2869%29.JPG">
<img id="summer" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Atlantic_Ocean_shoreline_in_Myrtle_Beach%2C_South_Carolina.jpg/220px-Atlantic_Ocean_shoreline_in_Myrtle_Beach%2C_South_Carolina.jpg">
<img id="autumn" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Maple_Trees_by_Creek.jpg/220px-Maple_Trees_by_Creek.jpg">
```

Answer (score -2):

Реализация на PHP если вдруг нужны кастомные диапазоны а не календарные

```
  $icons = array(
       "spring" => "images/spring.png",
       "summer" => "images/summer.png",
       "autumn" => "images/autumn.png",
       "winter" => "images/winter.png"
   );
   $day = date("z");
   $spring_starts = date("z", strtotime("March 21"));
   $spring_ends   = date("z", strtotime("June 20"));
   $summer_starts = date("z", strtotime("June 21"));
   $summer_ends   = date("z", strtotime("September 22"));
   $autumn_starts = date("z", strtotime("September 23"));
   $autumn_ends   = date("z", strtotime("December 20"));
   if( $day >= $spring_starts && $day <= $spring_ends ) :
           $season = "spring";
   elseif( $day >= $summer_starts && $day <= $summer_ends ) :
           $season = "summer";
   elseif( $day >= $autumn_starts && $day <= $autumn_ends ) :
           $season = "autumn";
   else :
           $season = "winter";
   endif;
   $image_path = $icons[$season];
   echo $image_path;
```

Comment: Пример с css-tricks на американский манер) Хотя бы под наши времена года поправили бы)

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, может вам еще и переменные на великом и могучем православном транслите поправить? За отдельную плату могём!